# multiprocessing. Как сделать задержку между Pool процессами

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Проблема заключается в том что если процессы срабатывают одновременно то код начинает криво работать. Поэтому нужна задержка перед началом работы, либо в самой функции.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def func():
   Можно сделать что бы именно в функции была задержка

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    test_data = ['profile1', 'profile2']
    pool.map(func, test_data)
```

Comment: Конечно, можно использовать `sleep`. Но в реальности вам необходимо организовать синхронизацию между процессами, если они не независимые. Например, через переменные состояния или события.

Comment: спасибо, углублюсь в это направление )

Comment: могли бы пожалуйста подсказать, какие функций входят в формулировку- состояние, событие?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives